# PyQGIS Passing value from a canvasPressEvent of MapTool to form in a plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, maptools

I am writing a plugin in QGIS 3.10.

I have a point layer and a line layer

I have a maptool that draws a line segment by snapping on the points of the point layer.
I managed to get the value of one attribute of the point layer where the line has been snapped to.
I get the value within the canvasPressEvent of my map tool.

I do not know how can I make to pass this value to the module where the map tool was called, where, after the geometry of the line is created, a form is opened to fill the required attributes by hand. I want this attribute be filled automatically, so there is no need to write it down.

Here is the code of my canvasPressEvent:

```
    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        layer_POLE = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('pole')[0]
        POLE_provider = layer_POLE.dataProvider() 
        sp_index = QgsSpatialIndex()
        
        for feat in layer_POLE.getFeatures():
             sp_index.insertFeature(feat)  
        
        if e.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            if self.status == 0:
                self.rb.reset(QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry)
                self.status = 1
            if self.snapIndicator.match().type():
                pointxy = self.snapIndicator.match().point()
                self.rb.addPoint(pointxy)
                
                nearest = sp_index.nearestNeighbor(pointxy,1)
                request = QgsFeatureRequest()
                request.setFilterFids(nearest)
                features = layer_POLE.getFeatures(request)
                for feature in features:
                    cab = feature['CAB']
                    print(feature['CAB'])
            else:
                self.rb.addPoint(self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos()))
 
        else:
            if self.rb.numberOfVertices() > 2:
                self.status = 0
                self.selectionDone.emit()
            else:
                self.reset()
        if cab:
            return cab
        else:
            return None
```